# How can I use DPDK with GridFTP?

Tags: ftp, dpdk

I am new to Data Plane Development Kit ([DPDK](https://www.dpdk.org)). I have the following questions.

1. How to use [DPDK](https://www.dpdk.org) with [GridFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GridFTP)? Please provide me an example.
2. How to use DPDK to transfer data between two host computer nodes? Please provide me an example.

[EDIT-1] from the comments

- DPDK version: 21.05.0 2
- NIC: SmartNIC (Bluefield as per the comment)
- DPDK TCP stack: Do not know yet but you can provide some suggestion (as an example).
- [GRID FTP code link](http://gridcf.org/gct-docs/6.0/gridftp/user/index.html)

Question: I want to allow GridFTP packets to be send over DPDK interface.

Comment: @BeautifulMing, I request to share the following information `1. DPDK version, 2. NIC planned to be used, 3. User space DPDK TCP stack, 4. Grid FTP code link,` for your first part of the question. With respect to second part I request to visit `dpdk.org` and documentation to better understand how physical nic based RX-TX works. Your question is not clear whether you want to integrate GridFTP or want to allow GridFTP packets to be send over DPDK interface. Hence I mark this as need for inforamtion

Comment: @VipinVarghese: For first part here are the answers.
1. DPDK version -- 21.05.0 
2. NIC planned to be used -- SmartNIC
3. User space DPDK TCP stack -- Do not know yet but you can provide some suggestion (as an example).
4. Grid FTP code link -- https://gridcf.org/gct-docs/6.0/gridftp/user/index.html

For second part, I want to allow GridFTP packets to be send over DPDK interface. I will appreciate your quick reponse.

Comment: thanks for the reply, there are handful of NIC which support DPDK, SInce you have mentioned SmartNIC I assume this is either Bluefield, netrnome, chelsio, or FPGA one. With regard to Grid packet send over DPDK, that can easily done with DPDK TAP|KNi interface. I can update the answer (assuming you are not asking for HW acceleration for GRIDFTP)

Comment: @VipinVarghese: I have access to Bluefield. I am not very familiar with GridFTP. Could you please provide me some code examples for questions 1 and 2 (mentioned in my first post)? That will be a great help.

Comment: please find the answers as `1) I would love to help on GridFTP, but I am not familiar with the same. But I assume there are some example code using GridFTP library, hence converting to use DPDK should be the real question`. With respect to 2nd question answer is `you can prepare your data in either L2, L3, L4 or any other layers and send it out. There is no direct example in DPDK but refer to pktmbuf_alloc and tx_burst. Also there are multiple GitHub local project which does the same`